# Function of d and t in sed substitution context

Tags: unix, sed, substitution

I used a substitution generator for sed and it gives me

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]+)￨m/\1￨T/gm;t;d'
```

I am familiar with regular expression flags g and m, but I have never seen the `t` and `d`. After looking them up it seems that t is for testing and d for deleting. But in this particular context, what does that mean? What do they contribute to the full command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting `sed` manual:

> `d`: Delete pattern space. Start next cycle.

> `t label`: If a `s///` has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to `label`; if `label` is omitted, branch to end of script.

In other words, if the `s` command succeeded, print the resulting pattern space, else skip (delete) the line.

Another way to express this is:

```
sed -n -E 's/([^ ]+) m/\1 T/gmp'
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I find it a bit odd that a tool would by default suggest a command that if a match cannot be found that the whole line should be deleted. I do not need this functionality (but I do need the `/g` flag), so I'll just remove the `;t;d` part then. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You know the context better than I. I see your sed command as a grep+modify, but more efficient than `grep | sed`.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is it's own "language" with it's own commands. It's not a "regular expression tool", but rather a "Stream EDitor".

> I am familiar with regular expression flags g and m,

The `s` command has it's own modifiers and `m` is a GNU extension. I do not really see how it's used here, as `sed` reads here one line at a time, and `m` modifies the behavior of `^` and `$`....

> But in this particular context, what does that mean?

In any possible context, `t` command jumps to the label if (any) `s///` command was successful. If label is omitted, it jumps to the end of script.

The `d` command deletes pattern space, effectively removing the line in typical parsing.

The `t;d` is a mnemonic to remove the line if the last `s` command was unsuccessful. I prefer to do `/pattern/!d; s//replacement/g` which is more readable to my eyes.

A reference for sed behavior would be the [posix sed documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and [gnu sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Thanks. I had found some documentation, but it is rather obscure if you are not familiar with how this exactly works. It wasn't clear to me what would get deleted, but apparently the whole input. I find it a bit odd that the tool that I used would by default suggest a command that if a match cannot be found that the whole line should be deleted. I do not need this functionality (but I do need the `/g` flag), so I'll just remove the `;t;d` part then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `sed` takes some time to understand what it's going on there, with that all pattern and hold space.